# Derivatives of functions in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

Let $V = C_{c}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ a space of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support. This basically means the space consists of all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that the $n$th derivative exists for all $n \ge 1$ and that $f$ is $0$ outside some bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$. We can denote differentiation as $D: V \to V, g \mapsto g'$. Then, we can define its dual to be $D^*: V^* \to V^*$ such that $D^*(f) = f \circ D$

Define another linear map $\phi_{f}$ such that $\phi_{f}(g) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x)dx$

I want to show that if the derivative of $f$ exists and is continuous, $-D^*(\phi_{f}) = \phi_{f'}$. I just tried plugging in $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x)dx$ into map $D$ which would get $f(x)g(x)$ and then that would give $f(f(x)g(x))$ but I don't think this is a correct way to do it. (Thanks for the answer, that was such a stupid mistake).

The second part of the question makes $f = 1$ if $x \ge 0$ and $f = 0$ if $x \lt 0$. Then, I am supposed to show that $-D^*(\phi_{f}) = \sigma$ where $\sigma(g)=g(0)$. We know that $f(x)$ is not differentiable. We can see the left side can be split into two intervals: $\int_{-\infty}^0 f(x)g'(x)dx + \int_0^{\infty} f(x)g'(x)dx$. Left term would be 0 because of $f$'s definition so integrating 0 would give you a constant. Right term would just be $\int_0^{\infty} g'(x)dx$ but I am not sure how to progress from here. $\sigma \in V^*$ just to make it clear.

The third part is that if you take $\phi \in V^*$ so that $D^*(\phi) = 0$, then $\phi = \phi_{f}$ where $f(x) = c$ for a real constant $c$. I just have no clue how to do this. Can someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is about how well you understand the notation, and this means that your approximation was right, just plug the correct objects in the correct equations:

$$D^*(\phi_f)(g)=\phi_f\circ D(g)=\phi_f(g')=\int_0^\infty f(x)g'(x)dx$$

Now you can finish using integration by parts and the "boundary" conditions given.

Comment: I updated the question. Mind taking a look if you can? Thanks